# How to implement two xib cells and single . Array count is nil show empty one otherwise show with data cell

Tags: ios, swift

How to implement two xib cells and  only one array, if array count is nil show empty xib cell and if array count is not nil show xib cell with data swift. Please solve the problem i have searched lot of no answer is related to me.

Comment: Dequeue the cell according to your need. What have you tried? You want to show an "empty state"?

Answer (score 0):

This example assumes your data array is named `myData`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // return either 1, or the count of your data, whichever is greater
    return max(1, myData.count)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // if it's the first row, and your data is empty
    if indexPath.row == 0 && myData.count == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emptyCell", for: indexPath) as! EmptyCell
        return cell;
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell
    // populate the cell
    return cell
}
```